# Mysql Select Correlation 2 Levels Deep Subqueries

Tags: mysql

I'm stuck and this is driving me crazy... I'd like to use the code below to get x number of wins in the row. The problem is, mysql only allows 1 correlation level (not sure if im explaining this right) but `@id` is supposed to return the players id from the first select query. Any idea on how I can make this work?

```
    select (@rank := if(@points = points, @rank +1, if(@points := points, @rank + 1, @rank + 1 ))) as rank, er.* from (select
@id := cc6_MensLeague_players.id as `id`,
@rounds := (
ifnull((select sum(p1.w)
from (
select 
@r1 := (case when p1_r1 like '%' then 1 else 0 end) as r1,
@r2 := (case when p1_r2 like '%' then 1 else 0 end) as r2,
@r3 := (case when p1_r3 like '%' then 1 else 0 end) as r3,
@r4 := (case when p1_r4 like '%' then 1 else 0 end) as r4,
(@r1+@r2+@r3+@r4) as w
from cc6_MensLeague_scoresheets where p1 = @id
)p1),0)
) as `rounds`,
sum((@rounds*2)+(@rounds*1)) as `points`
from cc6_MensLeague_players group by `id`) er cross join (select @rank := 0, @points := -1) params order by id desc limit 9;
```

Here is some sample data to play with:

(Using dynamic @id alias will not work)
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ao2zgyiy8U5doGER6XZT23/3

(Using static id 8 works perfectly)
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2f2KvZt5MHVUuaP3WLPmAi/2

Here is what the resulting output should be:

```
rank    id  rounds  points
1   10  4   12
2   9   4   12
3   8   8   24
4   7   8   24
5   6   6   18
6   5   4   12
7   4   0   0
8   3   0   0
9   2   0   0
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Minimal Sample data and corresponding expected output would help.

Comment: Hi Madhur, thanks for the quick response. I have added some sample data for you to take a look at.

Comment: And, what should be the expected output ? Please add that to the question in tabular format.

Comment: Just added the expected output.